# configure additonal build files in the @wordpress/create-block

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, block-editor, react

I'm using the @wordpress/create-block package to create my block plugin. It comes with preconfigured webpack settings to build all the assets. By default as js in the src/ folder is built in the build/index.js file.

However I want to be able to create a seperate js file in the build folder. I created the file src/view.js but can't see how I can configure that to be built in the build/ folder as all webpack config is hidden.